# Google Apps Script for Forms: Want to send users specific number on email

Tags: google-apps-script

It is possible to ask users to write their email addresses in FORM and after that they recieve email with unique number?

I find out how to send automatic email to submitter here - http://www.labnol.org/internet/auto-confirmation-emails/28386/

But don't know how to send to him unique number each!

Comment: what kind of unique number do you want to send him back? you could send him the unique id of the form response or for example a MD5 of his email adress: in the Amit Agarwal script replace: message = "We have received your details.<br>Thanks!<br><br>Your unique Id: "+Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, e.namedValues["Email Address"].toString()));

Comment: I want to send users "unique id of the form response". Better to start with 1 and go after that with other numbers... But also i need to get this number myself and place it in table that creates automaticly for my drive form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try the above code to retrieve the unique id of the form response. But it's not sorted numbers(1,2,...). It's a unique random number generated by the form. my advice is not to try to build something starting to 1 and going further, as it's assynchronious you do not have the security to to have a sorted list of items. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144261/getting-latest-form-response-sometimes-gets-the-one-before-it-instead) for details.

```
/**
* for a form with 2 question named "question 1" and "question 2"
* this function need to be associated directly to the form
* and it need to be associated to a trigger "on form submit"
* the "e" given as argument is generated by the form submit trigger
*/
function submitFormFunc(e) {
  var items = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var responses={};
  for(var i = 0; i< items.length; i++) {
   responses[items[i].getItem().getTitle()]=items[i].getResponse();
  }

  var responseTable = [];
  var responseIndex = ["Timestamp","ID","question 1","question 2"];
  responseTable.push(e.response.getTimestamp().toString());
  responseTable.push(e.response.getId());
  responseTable.push(responses["question 1"]); // my form have 2 questions named "question 1" and "question 2"
  responseTable.push(responses["question 2"]);
  responseTable.push(FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponse(e.response.getId()).getEditResponseUrl());
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID").appendRow(responseTable);
}
```

--EDIT--

if You want something shorter you can use the time stamp:

change (or add) `responseTable.push(e.response.getTimestamp().toString());` for

```
responseTable.push(e.response.getTimestamp().getTime().toString());
```

or even shorter but a little less efficient:

you can add a line:

```
responseTable.push(generateUnique());
```

and add the function:

```
function generateUnique(){
  var vals =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID").getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var ids=[];
  for(var i in vals){
    ids.push(vals[0]);
  }
  var newId = Math.floor(Math.random()*100); // change 100 for something bigger if needed
  while(ids.indexOf(newId)>-1){
    newId = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
  }
  Logger.log(newId);
  return(newId);
}
```

Comment: Harold thank you for your time! I manage to succeed the code and is working, but send me this: Your unique Id: gJnyU5iJKgI32Ep/UCKqWg==

This is too much complicated. The form is needet to collect data for Sports Tournament Registration, and users need to know their number, we also need to know users number. But we need some simple numbers here.. not this kind of digits and letters.. How to do that?

Every user has specific TimeStamp when he send us his information. How to send user this TimeStamp. In this case TimeStamp will be the Unique Number we want to have!

Comment: I edited the anwser so you can use the timestamp or even a shorter marker

Comment: Harlond thank you, but i'm not a programmer and can't understand how to place this code to work. Can i ask you to see my entire code here, and tell me how to add TimeStamp into it: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UZDUzuMjm5RaNU1FOneoDBefstpJh3D4GbSdQvBhBSY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok i find a way to get TimeStamp in email message. Just need to delete this: if ((i !== "0") && (value !== ""))

Comment: i need your help again :)

I need to make above code with unique number between 100 is work for me, but it isn't!

I make everything you write above but not working! Here it is: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hnSoXPZmckjKCP7BVoQFHuCTEhw8O9L1_xA3QJOu3Js/edit?usp=sharing

You can see that my code include 3 questions. I include code directly to drive form (not excel tables with the results) and add trigger (submitFormFunc) on Form Submit. It's not working. Please i need to make your code working for me. THANKS!

Comment: the whole stuff here: https://docs.google.com/a/ousset.net/forms/d/1hXaZ2X-7lV9Ba6SrgQ4zQXY1ydETdBlMQleT2RCwPP0/viewform (the code is in the spreadsheet you will get after ansewring the form)

Comment: OMG i try everything, but nothing happen. Please add mishef@gmail.com to spreadsheet and form. I will clone them in my google drive and working with them. Thanks!

Comment: Ok this is exactly what i do: https://docs.google.com/document/d/19O-vUVgAYOjvRqb9Een1uGO_rt3LGW1lVxhE7cTEhV4/edit?usp=sharing and it's not working right....

Comment: Everything is working fine, but HTML tags in script not show well in email. How to fix that? https://docs.google.com/document/d/19O-vUVgAYOjvRqb9Een1uGO_rt3LGW1lVxhE7cTEhV4/edit