# Write a unique code when submit google form (script)

Tags: google-apps-script

when sending a form, the "sendform(e)" adds a unique code to the cell adjacent to the insert, but I can not understand why not work for me.

Can anyone help me?

```
    function sendform(e) 
{ 



var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

e.namedValues['CODICE'] = CodeGen("llnnnnn");

}

function CodeGen(CodeStr,ExclStr) {
........
}
```

Comment: I've got something similar with a different approch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631922/google-apps-script-for-forms-want-to-send-users-specific-number-on-email/21672812#21672812

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really didn't give enough code for me to see what's going on with your code, but here's a solution I wrote from scratch that you can modify to fit your needs.  I commented the crap out of it so you can see how it works.  I also drew from a number of sources to find a random alphanumeric generator that I felt comfortable would meet your needs.

```
function formResponses(e) {
  var formData = e.values;//obtains form data submitted
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1eVEM9vN7Hzn-pKhtyDHBXhQvoVmePJr6Su5ipTK9Shs');//opens response Spreadsheet that is linked to form, put your response sheet ID here
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Responses');//opens response sheet to read/write, put your response sheet name here
  var userEmail = formData[2];//gets user email, but does not store it, it is discarded after email is sent.
  var lastCol = 4;//sets column where uniqueId will be written
  var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();//row where new form entries are added
  var speciesResponse = formData[1];//retrieves user's response to the form question

  //the next line retrieves a list of existing IDs from the last column of the resopnse sheet
  var uuIdArray = [sh.getRange(2,lastCol,sh.getLastRow(),1)];
  //the next line create a new random string for this submission by calling the generation string
  //with arguments a string of 8 16-bit characters
  var randomId = genRandomString(8,16);
  //the following for() loop compares the newly generated random string
  //to the existing UniqueIds, and if there is a duplicate,
  //it regenerates another randomId and resets i = 0 to compare from the first unique ID again.
  //if there is not a duplicate within the list, it will finish the for loop and move on.
  for (var i = 0; i < uuIdArray.length; i++){
    if (randomId == uuIdArray[i]){
      var randomId = genRandomString(8,16)
      i = 0
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(lastRow,lastCol,1,1).setValue(randomId);
  Logger.log(randomId);
  var species = speciesId(speciesResponse);
  Logger.log(species);
  var fromAlias = selectSenderEmailAlias();
  sendSpeciesEmail(userEmail,species, randomId, fromAlias);
  Logger.clear();//clears the log of identifying information, specifically user's email address.
  sh.getRange(2,3,sh.getLastRow(),1).clear();
}

//SUPPLEMENTAL FUNCTIONS CALLED FROM THE FORM POST:

//This is the important part for generating the random 8 digit Unique ID  
function genRandomString(len, bits){
  bits = bits || 36;
  var outStr = "", newStr;
  while (outStr.length < len)
  {
    newStr = Math.random().toString(bits).slice(2);
    outStr += newStr.slice(0, Math.min(newStr.length, (len - outStr.length)));
  }
  return outStr.toUpperCase();
}
//The rest of this is for fun to test the form and a mailer to notify the user of their species status
function speciesId(speciesResponse){
  var species = speciesResponse;
  switch (species){
    case "Yes":
      var userType = "Human";
      break;
    case "No":
      var userType = "Other";
      break;
  }
  return userType;
}

//selects an Alias to obscure mailing address from form author
function selectSenderEmailAlias(){
  var alias = GmailApp.getAliases();
  Logger.log(alias[0]);
  return alias;
}

//constructs and mails the user their results.
function sendSpeciesEmail(userEmail,species,randomId,fromAlias){
  var userEmail = userEmail;
  var emailFrom = 'Helperbot@hyperbole.com';
  var species = species;
  Logger.log(species);
  var fromAlias = fromAlias;
  var subject = 'Species evlauation quiz. Confirmation# '+randomId;
  var randomId = randomId;
  switch(species){
    case "Human":
      var body = 'Congrats! You are a human!';
      break;
    case "Other":    
      var body = 'Uh oh. I have bad news. You may be a cat (or another sub-human species).  Please contact your physician for further evaluation';
      break;
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body, {from: fromAlias});
}
```

Here is the folder to view the files: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_5rNbCI5MM9ellxaGdrWlItNVE&usp=sharing  The script is found under Tools>Manage Scripts in the response spreadsheet.

Here's the form to test if it works or not (https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Cz6U92w-vAyoofshbXcScNi6S2WWdRLw0srYfguplnU/viewform).  Look at the spreadsheet for responses in column C to see the unique ID that is generated.  I can't possibly verify that the ID iterator will never mess up, but by the design of the code, I can't imagine that it won't work.  However, there's no way to put a value in there as a test case, since it will generate a randomId as soon as a form is submitted.

I tried to find my source again for the random string generator, but I can't since I closed a bunch of tabs.  My apologies to the original author.

Comment: Your approach to the problem I like a lot. I had a bit of difficulty at first but after a few hours of reading I understood perfectly what does your script. I find it very useful and accurate. Thanks.

Comment: @thoughtcrime I can figure out how the formResponses handler is atttached to a trigger in the spreadsheet. All triggers are empty. Trying it I can see it works, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: 2,534 views, 253 IDs generated, 3.75 years, and an average of 30 forms submissions per month, and my post still has a score of zero.  : |

It's not the cleanest code in the world, and could be improved, but...no love at all?

Answer (score 0):

To generate random strings using this function very complete.

```
function CodeGen(CodeStr,ExclStr) {
// a = code string, b = string of characters to exclude
  var i=0;
  var alen = CodeStr.length;
  var areturn = ""
  for (i=0;i<=alen;i++)
       {
       areturn=areturn+RandChar(CodeStr.substring(i,i+1),ExclStr);
       }
  return(areturn);
}

function RandChar(a,b) {
  var usestring = GenString(a,b);
  var randchar = Math.floor(Math.random()*usestring.length);
  return(usestring.substring(randchar,randchar+1));    
       }

function GenString(a,b) {
  var numstring = ExcludeString('0123456789',b);
  var charstring = ExcludeString('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',b);
  var allstring = numstring+charstring;
  switch (a) {
    case 'a': 
      result = allstring; 
      break;
    case 'n': 
      result = numstring; 
      break;
    case 'l': 
      result = charstring; 
      break;
    case 'v': //118 = v
    case 'w': //119 = w
    case 'x':
    case 'y':
      result = allstring.substr(0, a.charCodeAt(0)-122+allstring.length);
      break;
    default: result = a;
             }
  return(result);
}

function ExcludeString(FullText, ExcludeText) {
  FullText=FullText+''
  ExcludeText=ExcludeText+''
  var areturn = ''
  var SearchText = ''
  for (i=0;i<=FullText.length;i++)
    {
    SearchText = FullText.substring(i,i+1)
    if (ExcludeText.search(SearchText) == -1)
      {  
      areturn=areturn+SearchText;
      }
    }
    return(areturn);
}
```

Examples:

CodeGen("xa-aaaa-aaaa") gives PN-4ZES-UN57 or 0T-TY1R-7NUI

CodeGen("aa-aaaa-aaaa","0O1I5S") gives PN-4ZEU-UNT7 or 3T-TY4R-7NUK

CodeGen("llnnnnn") gives VF98029, two letters then five numbers

CodeGen("IC-nnnn") gives IC-7233 or IC-2743, always starts with IC

CodeGen("nn-nnnn") gives 01-2945 or 65-2329

CodeGen("nnnnnnn","0135679") gives 884422 or 2428242, excluding

I find this feature very useful because it is very customizable. I wanted to thank the original author of this feature, but I do not know who has created a very nice tool(code).