# Google Sheets On Form Submit Event - Complete Code Before Next Submission

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using an On Form Submission trigger in a Google Sheet that I created.  The problem that I am having is that there is a chance that the form could be submitted quicker than it takes to execute the code, so the first submission is interrupted.

Ideally, I would like it to complete the execution for the first submission, and as soon as it completes, begin on the second submission.  Is this possible?

Comment: in your script you didn't try by writing two functions else can you share your script code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting latest Form Response sometimes gets the one before it instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144261/getting-latest-form-response-sometimes-gets-the-one-before-it-instead)

Comment: Are you certain that your problem is concurrency itself? Don't be too quick to seize on a solution that serializes operations if you don't need to. For example, if your trigger function assumes a static spreadsheet with the responses it needs to deal with _in the last row_, fix __that__.

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

[`LockService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/) or deal with concurrency.

Others have begun investigating using Firebase as an alternative to the in-built LockService due to recent reliability issues.

Personally the latter option is my recommendation. i.e. Have your project cope with multiple entry points at uncontrollable times.

Comment: you can also use cacheService as a faster alternative than using an external database

Answer (score 0):

Good luck, I have been fighting for a good solution for over a year now (with my Choice Eliminator add-on).  The problem is that Google process your script after the form is submitted, so there is no real way to prevent overlapping submissions.

Here is what I have found.

1. You can temporarly shut off the form from accepting answers:   This was actually the best way I have found, but it tended to confuse the end-user, and they also potentially lost the info they filled out if they hit submit and it was closed.    I also found that if there was any hiccup in the onFormSubmit function the form would stay closed until the owner re-opened it.
2. LockService.   I tested this and it really didn't do anything to help with the overlapping submissions.  It prevented my code from running twice, but then my code didn't run on the second submission.
3. I personally chose to remove everything and make the script run as fast as possible.   With one exception, I grabbed the time the script started, and ended, then displayed the difference to the owner of the script so they at least knew how long there needed to be between submissions to not have an error.