# Ensure e.namedValues gets current responses

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, race-condition, google-forms

I'm developing a Google Apps Script bound to a Google Sheet and I've encountered problems using the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) passed by the onFormSubmit() trigger to reliably access the most recent form answers when there is a deleted question with the same title as a current question.

If the user deletes a form question and creates a new one with the same name ("Question Title"), accesssing the question response using `e.namedValues[ "Question Title"]` pulls in the response from the old deleted question which is invariably nothing as the question is deleted and cannot be answered.

I know I can try getting the form responses directly from the form with something like, `FormApp.openByUrl(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getFormUrl()).getResponses()` but I'd rather avoid that as it will significantly slow down my script and more importantly, cause my script to be inaccurate and buggy due to the responses not being the most recent responses [(race conditions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144261/getting-latest-form-response-sometimes-gets-the-one-before-it-instead?answertab=active#tab-top).

What can I do to make sure `e.namedValue` is fetching the most recent question when there is a deleted question with the same title as a current question?

Comment: Every answer in the response will be represented by a unique `namedValue`; by default that will be the original text of the question, which is convenient, but the possibility of identical questions is handled by decorating the name some way. If you dump the event object you'll see all the names used... then pick the one you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For questions with the identical names ("Question Titles"), `e.namedValues[ "Question Title"]` holds an array with responses listed from the least to most recently created question. Therefore, the last element in the array holds the response to the most recently created question.

So to retrieve the response to the latest created question with a particular name ("question title") you would use something like this

```
e.namedValues["Question Title"][e.namedValues["Question Title"].length - 1]
```